# System Down KVM

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kvm, proxmox

I have an issus with my proxmox server. Sometime I cannot access to my server.
Ping or Ssh does not work, I have tried to connect my screen to the server to check what's happen but I have no image.
The server is on I can hear fan on.

I'am using proxmox ( KVM ) I have checked the log but I have have found nothing in log between 6:25 am and 12:50 Pm, I have restarted using button at 12:50 pm.
Can you tell me which log I can check or any idea ?

```
cat /var/log/messages

Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.275269] vmbr0: port 2(fwpr105p0) entered 

blocking state
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.275271] vmbr0: port 2(fwpr105p0) entered disabled state
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.275331] device fwpr105p0 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.275358] vmbr0: port 2(fwpr105p0) entered blocking state
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.275360] vmbr0: port 2(fwpr105p0) entered forwarding state
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.277620] fwbr105i0: port 2(veth105i0) entered blocking state
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.277621] fwbr105i0: port 2(veth105i0) entered disabled state
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.277672] device veth105i0 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.351567] eth0: renamed from vethRS2AYN
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve pve-ha-lrm[2245]: <root@pam> end task UPID:pve:000008C8:0000355B:5DEFCFC9:vzstart:105:root@pam: OK
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.648166] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.648174] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.648208] fwbr105i0: port 2(veth105i0) entered blocking state
Dec 10 18:03:50 pve kernel: [  181.648210] fwbr105i0: port 2(veth105i0) entered forwarding state
Dec 11 03:20:53 pve pveupdate[22976]: <root@pam> starting task UPID:pve:000059D3:00334700:5DF05285:aptupdate::root@pam:
Dec 11 03:20:56 pve pveupdate[22976]: <root@pam> end task UPID:pve:000059D3:00334700:5DF05285:aptupdate::root@pam: OK
Dec 11 06:25:13 pve liblogging-stdlog:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0" x-pid="1134" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Dec 11 23:54:34 pve pvedaemon[1934]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Dec 11 23:54:40 pve pvedaemon[1934]: <root@pam> starting task UPID:pve:000039B8:00A43BC4:5DF173B0:qmstart:114:root@pam:
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.572724] device tap114i0 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.593096] fwbr114i0: port 1(fwln114i0) entered blocking state
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.593097] fwbr114i0: port 1(fwln114i0) entered disabled state
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.593157] device fwln114i0 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.593186] fwbr114i0: port 1(fwln114i0) entered blocking state
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.593188] fwbr114i0: port 1(fwln114i0) entered forwarding state
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.595855] vmbr0: port 3(fwpr114p0) entered blocking state
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.595857] vmbr0: port 3(fwpr114p0) entered disabled state
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.595921] device fwpr114p0 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.595936] vmbr0: port 3(fwpr114p0) entered blocking state
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.595937] vmbr0: port 3(fwpr114p0) entered forwarding state
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.598134] fwbr114i0: port 2(tap114i0) entered blocking state
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.598136] fwbr114i0: port 2(tap114i0) entered disabled state
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.598194] fwbr114i0: port 2(tap114i0) entered blocking state
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve kernel: [107633.598195] fwbr114i0: port 2(tap114i0) entered forwarding state
Dec 11 23:54:41 pve pvedaemon[1934]: <root@pam> end task UPID:pve:000039B8:00A43BC4:5DF173B0:qmstart:114:root@pam: OK
Dec 12 00:09:28 pve pvedaemon[1934]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Dec 12 00:24:29 pve pvedaemon[1935]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Dec 12 00:39:30 pve pvedaemon[1936]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Dec 12 00:54:31 pve pvedaemon[1934]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Dec 12 01:09:32 pve pvedaemon[1934]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Dec 12 01:24:32 pve pvedaemon[31249]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Dec 12 01:39:33 pve pvedaemon[31249]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Dec 12 01:54:34 pve pvedaemon[1521]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Dec 12 02:09:35 pve pvedaemon[31283]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Dec 12 02:24:36 pve pvedaemon[1521]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Dec 12 02:39:37 pve pvedaemon[31249]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'
Dec 12 04:42:01 pve pveupdate[7733]: <root@pam> starting task UPID:pve:00001E5C:00BE8A77:5DF1B709:aptupdate::root@pam:
Dec 12 04:42:03 pve pveupdate[7733]: <root@pam> end task UPID:pve:00001E5C:00BE8A77:5DF1B709:aptupdate::root@pam: OK
Dec 12 06:25:05 pve liblogging-stdlog:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0" x-pid="1134" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Dec 12 12:50:45 pve kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.18-23-pve (build@pve) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)) #1 SMP PVE 4.15.18-51 (Wed, 13 Nov 2019 11:20:34 +0100) ()
Dec 12 12:50:45 pve kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.18-23-pve root=/dev/mapper/pve-root ro quiet amd_iommu=on
Dec 12 12:50:45 pve kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Dec 12 12:50:45 pve kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
```

Thanks

Comment: Today I had new issue, i have let my screen and keyboard plugued and I can see login screen but nothing happen when I tried to enter login, nothing on the screen, like my keyboard it's not pluged, it's working after hard reboot. So I will try to start my system using older kernel, will see if it will fixe the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming from ram, I have just done memtest and now Since 7 days I had no system down.